# What is the equivalent operator in R for matlab /

Tags: r, matlab

I have one program in Matlab that I want translate to a R program.

The matlab program is :

```
function R = cprob(N,A,B)
    R = ((A.*B)*N)/(B*N)
end
```

In R, " * " becomes " %*% " and " .* " becomes " * ". And " / "?

Comment: Not everyone knows matlab.  This is why reproducible examples are encouraged.  What does `/` do in matlab? [edited]

Comment: Division of matrices is not uniquely defined, and can be either `ginv(B) %*% A` or `A %*% ginv(B)` where `ginv` is generalised R function for solving inverse of matrix.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116607/r-right-matrix-division) can help

Comment: A %*% ginv(B) gives me equal answers. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that by `"/"` you mean a matrix right division.

You can use `mrdivide` frim the `pracma` package.  Please take a look at this.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/mldivide

This would be your code:

```
    library("pracma")

    a1 = matrix(c(1,2,0,2,5,-1,4,10,-1),nrow=3,ncol=3) 
    a2 = matrix(c(1,2,4,2,5,10,0,-1,-1),nrow=3,ncol=3) 
    a3=  matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),nrow=3,ncol=3) 


    myfunction<-function (N,A,B) {
      return(round(mrdivide((A*B)%*%N,B %*% N))) 
    }

    result_matrix<-myfunction(a1,a2,a3)
```

Which gives you the result you stated in the comments.

Comment: for matrices:

a1 = [1 2 0; 2 5 -1; 4 10 -1]
a2 = [1 2 4; 2 5 10; 0 -1-1]
a3 = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]

In Matlab cprob(a1,a2,a3):

   1  -0  -0
   0   5  -0
   0  -0  -1

In R with the function

    cprob <- function(N,A,B){
        return(mrdivide((A * B) %*% N, B %*% N))
    }

I have a different result:

    13.8   32 -2.4
    -6.4  -15  1.2
    -4.8  -12  1.4

Comment: Hi Isac. I get the same result. Please check my code!

Comment: you are right! :) . But I followed the solution suggested by @ANG and I wrote:
    cprob <- function(N,A,B){
        return(((A * B) %*% N) %*% solve(B %*% N))
    }

Thank you both for helping me. :)